# Master Page loading infinitely

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have an issue whenever I run my code with **MasterPage** and **ContentPage holder**, the page never finishes loading completely. The control *toggles* from the `Page_Load` of the master page to `Page_Load` of the ContentPage infinitely.

Here is my code:

Master `Page_Load`:

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string domainUserName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Page.User.Identity.Name) ? (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name) : (Page.User.Identity.ToString());
            this.Session["UserName"] = domainUserName.ToString().Split('\\').Last();
            lbl_UserName.Text = this.Session["UserName"].ToString();
            ValidateAuthorization(domainUserName);
            LoadMyPDlData();
        }
```

Content `Page_Load`:

```
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            lMessage.Visible = false;
            btn_Upload.Enabled = true;
            lMessage.Text = "";
            btnSaveunknown.Visible = false;
            btnAddRow.Visible = false;
            txt_PdlName.Text = "";
        }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a problem with either ValidateAuthorization or LoadMyPDlData. Try run them isolated

Comment: Infinite redirects can be a symptom of not properly handling browser's with cookies disabled or not allowed for your site.

Comment: when you step through in debug mode, what happens?

Comment: @TryingToImprove sounds right to me.  Comment out those method calls and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: I tried removing the ValidateAuthorization(domainUserName)            LoadMyPDlData() function but din help.When I debug the control goes to pageLoad of ContentPage after finishing the pageLoad event, the control goes to PageLoad of Master page which after completion loads my page on browser but the control goes again to the JAVASCRIPT of Content PageLoad and the process repeats.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the error.The problem was with the Jquery I had added in .aspx page which was throwing error and hence the page was going in infinite loop.Removed it and the problem solved!!!
Thanks to everyone for your suggestion.